Find a matrix $Q$ that has $Q(Q^T)=I$ but does not have orthonormal columns
My textbook says that if a matrix $Q$ is square and has orthonormal columns then $Q(Q^T)=I$, but it does not say the opposite (that if $Q(Q^T)=I$ then $Q$ has orthonormal columns). Is there an example of such a matrix $Q$ that has the property $Q(Q^T)=I$ but does not have orthonormal columns?

By definition, no

If you treat $Q$ as a collection of row vectors, work through a few simple examples to see what the matrix multiplication is telling you.

By the way, technically orthonormal columns means $Q^TQ=I$ and orthonormal rows means $QQ^T=I$. These are equivalent for square $Q$ since then they are both equivalent to $Q^{-1}=Q^T$.

Maybe it depends which inner product is taken for determining of the orthogonality ?

Let the columns of the matrix P be vectors $(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n)$, for example
$$
x_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
a_2 \\
a_3 \\
\vdots \\
a_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$\forall a_i \in \Bbb R$
so $P^{T}$ is the matrix whose rows are vectors
$$
P^{T} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^{T} \\
x_2^{T} \\
x_3^{T} \\
\vdots \\
x_n^{T} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then by definition of orthogonality $P^{T}*P=I$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^{T} \\
x_2^{T} \\
x_3^{T} \\
\vdots \\
x_n^{T} \\
\end{pmatrix}
*
(x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n) =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1^{T}x_1 & x_1^{T}x_2 \cdots x_1^{T}x_n \\
x_2^{T}x_1 & x_2^{T}x_2 \cdots x_2^{T}x_n \\
\vdots & \vdots  \\
x_n^{T}x_1 & x_n^{T}x_2 \cdots x_n^{T}x_n \\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \cdots 0 \\
0 & 1 \cdots 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 \cdots 1 \\
\end{pmatrix} = I
$$
By comparison, for each vector, its inner product is $1$ hence a unit vector, while any other inner product is $0$ hence it's orthogonal to every other vector ex: $x_i^{T}x_i =  1$ while $x_i^{T}x_j = 0,  i \ne j$

If I'm following correctly, this shows that (Q^T)Q=I if Q has orthonormal columns, but it doesn't show that Q(Q^T)=I if Q has orthonormal columns. Does this mean that if Q has orthonormal columns then Q(Q^T) does not necessarily equal the identity matrix?

Barring any idiosyncrasies (non-square matrices, complex matrices etc) , if $P$ is orthornormal then so is $P^{T}$. In that case $P*P^{T}$ is equal to $P^{T}*P$
